# Redmine JSON.parse leads to Internal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, redmine

i created a redmine plugin that creates an additional page. In the page template I just want to convert a JSON to an array and print it.

My code looks like this:

```
<% require 'json' %>

<% jsonArray = [{"content":"1D","createdTime":"09-06-2011 00:59"},{"content":"2D","createdtime":"09-06-2011 08:00"}] %>

<% objArray = JSON.parse(jsonArray) %>

<%= objArray.html_safe %>
```

But as soon as I start to use the `JSON.parse` redmine gets an error that looks like this:

> Internal error
>   An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
>   If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.
>
> If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.
>
> Back

I installed the ruby 'json' gem.

*Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonArray` is not a JSON array, but a normal Ruby array. To generate JSON from it, you need to use `#to_json` method. I'm not sure what's the point of generating JSON and parsing it right afterwards though.

Answer (score 0):

One method of debugging Redmine's "Internal error" messages would be to **monitor it's logs.**

If you are running it on Linux, best way is to

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

of if you are running Redmine in development mode, it would be:

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

Additionally, to have better errors, instead of just "something went wrong", you can add rubygems like better error gem from 
https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors

to add it, just open your Gemfile

and paste:

```
group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end
```

Then run `bundle install` again.
(Keep in mind that it's added under "development" group, so your redmine has to be run in development mode.